# Will a housekeeping flyback require EMI filtering?

Tags: power-supply, power-electronics, switch-mode-power-supply, flyback, emi-filtering

I'm interested in designing a hobby custom power supply in SPICE using a full bridge converter topology. I will have various components which will require biasing, so I was also thinking of using a flyback converter to provide internal bias throughout the board.

Startup regulator --> flyback --> full bridge & other housekeeping biasing

I will be adding EMI input filtering for the full bridge.

Will the flyback converter also need an EMI filter? If it needs filtering, it will add a lot of bulk which makes me wonder why a flyback is even used at all for housekeeping.

Comment: Addendum #1: flyback would be in DCM

Comment: What's the input? Mains? And what are the power levels?

Comment: 28VDCIN, Full Bridge ~ 500W, Flyback ~ 10W (guesstimate)

Answer (score 4):

> Will the flyback converter also need an EMI filter?

If you want to comply to the EMC regulation the answer is yes.

---

In 2017 I successfully EMC and UL tested a 50 W flyback converter 230VAC/12VDC at 4A and here are some hints for you:

1. The toughest test is called "Conducted Emission Test" and it is carried out in the frequency range 9 kHz to 30 MHz.

In the test the board is placed on a wood table placed above a big circular  metal plate connected to the earth terminal of the measurement system.

Your board and the plate are a capacitor.

The power supply induces in air some displacement current from the large metal plate connected to Earth.

This displacement current is due to the varying electric field that the power supply has with respect to the earth metal big plate.

See this picture from Wikipedia:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Displacement_current

[image]

The displacement current is the Maxwell's term in the well known Maxwell's equations.

The test is meant to measure how much current the power supply induced to/from other electronic systems connected to earth.

The test is mandatory whether or not the power supply is connected to earth through its connector.

The only way to pass this test is by having a common mode input filter at the 230/110 VAC input. This filter limits the displacement current.

The bigger the output current is, the bigger the input filter must be.

---

Y capacitors may also come handy, in terms of EMC tests, when the power supply is by law connected to earth for example because it has an external metal cover.

Two Y capacitors are connected from line to earth and from to neutral to earth to limit the input displacement current.

The typical input filter is a common mode filter and a X2 capacitor between line and neutral.

---

Another way to reduce the power supply conducted emissions is reducing the length of the output cable.

In order to pass the test I had to cut the output cable by 4 inches (10 centimeters). The output cable length was reduced from 12 inches to 8.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, but merely draw power from after the EMI filter for the full-bridge.  It's the bigger source and will require much more filtering anyway (well, depends on topology and how well synchronized the edges are, but probably).  Why duplicate effort when you can filter everything at once?

It can also draw from post-PFC supply, if you are adding such feature.

Answer (score 0):

> Will the flyback converter also need an EMI filter?

Flyback, for me, is the most disgusting topology ever in terms of EMI. Even though one day nothing else requires an EMI filter whatsoever, a flyback will almost always require one, especially when it's running at DCM. Don't take it personally but I'd stay away from flyback unless it's the only way to hit the application and cost targets. Just as an FYI, there are smarter controllers today to decrease the EMI of low-power DCM flybacks (hint: frequency jittering).

The bias regulator will be supplied from the same source as your main regulator. Both of them are switching regulators, so why not employ a single EMI filter and supply both regulators from the filtered input?

> makes me wonder why a flyback is even used at all for housekeeping

Well, generally, you can get multiple isolated outputs with almost no hassle (there is a cross-regulation issue, of course, but sometimes not a big problem).

Comment: Doesn't the main EMI issue in flybacks come from the DCM ringing of the leakage inductance resonating with the switch capacitance? Switching frequency distribution doesn't even help against that.. So yeah flyback has few things going for it :)

Comment: @tobalt `Doesn't the main EMI issue in flybacks come from the DCM ringing of the leakage inductance resonating with the switch capacitance?` that's the switch ringing *(DCM has a specific resonance coming from magnetising inductance and switch capacitance)*. That, and diode ringing are always present regardless of the operation mode. And they can be "snubbed" or "clamped" to some (acceptable) extent. The input peak currents and therefore di/dt, however, are higher in a DCM flyback. Changing the switching frequency (or simply, changing on or off times) will alter the peaks as per V = L di/dt.